# How to get field declaration types other than primitive types in libclang?

Tags: c++, libclang

I'm trying to get field declaration types other than primitive types in libclang for a C++ AST.  Types like {int, float, etc.} can be decoded using clang_getTypeSpelling.  CXType is not a CXString,  I cannot deduce types like std::string etc because the following code reduces it to the string "int".   How can I read types like std::string in libclang?  I've poured over the doxygen interface code and cannot find the right method.

```
 clang_getCString(
     clang_getTypeSpelling(
         clang_getCursorType(
             clang_getTypeDeclaration(
                 clang_getCursorType(cursor)))))
```